# .NET Entity property as enum or object

Tags: c#, .net, model, data-access-layer, object-model

I need some advice on best practices when creating an Entity and setting its (what are effectively enums) properties in .NET.

To take a simple example, let's say I have an object called 'Todo', which has three properties:
    ID (int)
    Text (string)
    State (NotStarted, InProgress, Complete)

My Todo object will be stored in a SQL Server database, with the 'Type' property stored as an int. The State property will not have any other information or methods associated with it, it is just to mark the completeness of the Todo instance.

Should I be creating an enum (outside the Todo class) in Todo.cs as follows:

```
public enum TodoState  
{  
  NotStarted = 0,  
  InProgress = 1,  
  Complete = 2  
}
```

After which, I can create my Todo class as:

```
public class Todo
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Text { get; set; }
  public TodoState State { get; set; }
}
```

Or should I be creating a TodoState class that has an internal enum and static constructors? Or is there a better completely different way of doing this?

In addition to what you think would be the best way to achieve this in this instance, what are the industry standard way of approaching this kind of problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 5 (with .NET 4.5), Entity Framework supports `enum` properties. Read [Enum Support - Code First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859576.aspx) and [Enumeration Support in Entity Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/06/29/enumeration-support-in-entity-framework.aspx) for more information.

This is *by far* the easiest solution to your problem.

Your code looks good as is. I think you're on the right track, although here's a few minor suggestions:

- Standard practice is to define one type per `.cs` file, including enums, so I recommend moving `enum TodoState` to `TodoState.cs`.
- `TodoState` as a name works, but I think `CompletionState` is more descriptive of what it's supposed to represent.

Comment: It should be noted that EF5 only supports enums in the .NET Framework 4.5 or greater (Visual Studio 2012).  EF5 on VS2010 does not support them (technically it's EF4.4, but it's installed when you install 5)

Comment: @MystereMan However EF6 will support enums on .NET 4 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/10/30/ef6-alpha-1-available-on-nuget.aspx